# Trying to print even and odd numbers from a shared resource

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to print a synchronized Integer object (mInt) using two threads till 10. However either one of the thread locks the other thread throws the exception pasted below. Can someone point my mistake here. This is more of a Java related question however included "android" tag because I have coded it for android and I need to tryout sometime in it.

> 09-24 15:24:17.198  10621-11400/com.sameer.android.samplecode
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-364
>       Process: com.sameer.android.samplecode, PID: 10621
>       java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
>               at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
>               at com.sameer.android.samplecode.MainActivity$Even.run(MainActivity.java:55)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Integer mInt;

    class Odd extends Thread {
        private final String TAG = Odd.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Odd() Started....");
            synchronized (mInt) {
                try {
                    while (mInt <= 10)
                    {
                        while (mInt % 2 != 1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Odd... Looping " + mInt);
                            mInt.wait();
                        }
                        mInt++;
                        Log.i(TAG, "Odd " + mInt);
                        mInt.notify();
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Odd() " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Odd() Ended....");
        }
    }

    class Even extends Thread {
        private final String TAG = Even.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Even() Started....");
            synchronized (mInt) {
                try {
                    while (mInt <= 10)
                    {
                        while (mInt % 2 != 0) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Even... Looping " + mInt);
                            mInt.wait();
                        }
                        mInt++;
                        Log.i(TAG, "Even " + mInt);
                        mInt.notify();
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Even() " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Even() Ended....");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mInt = new Integer(0);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Even even = new Even();
                even.start();

                Odd odd = new Odd();
                odd.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increment `mInt`, you do **not modify** the current Integer object but **create a new** Integer object. Thus, the call to `notify` is performed on the new (unlocked) object. As `notify` must be called on the object that is locked, the `IllegalMonitorStateException` occurs.

*Additional Side Remark (not part of answer):*

Your code has a fundamental problem. You lock `mInt` at the beginning of both `run` methods. Thus, only one of your thread can enter its `synchronized` block. The second thread, will wait for the lock on `mInt` until the first thread leaves it `synchronized` block, ie, terminates. Thus, you end up in a **deadlock** because the first thread increments only a single time and waits inside its `synchronized` block for the other thread to do the next increment. However, the second thread cannot perform this operation as it cannot enter its own `synchronized` block (until the first thread releases the lock on `mInt`).

Comment: Hey Matthias, you first para was relevant to me. Appreciate your comment.

Comment: I feel you should also edit the second para. I may be misleading to others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matthias! Your response (partially) helped me solved the issue which I was suspecting and you nailed it. The issue was with mInt getting newly created and hence losing reference. I fixed the issue by creating a class  similar to Integer. I have pasted the code below.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Value mInt;

    class Odd extends Thread {
        private final String TAG = Odd.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Odd() Started....");
            synchronized (mInt) {
                try {
                    while (mInt.get() < 10)
                    {
                        while (mInt.get() % 2 != 1) {
                            mInt.wait();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "Odd " + mInt.get());
                        mInt.inc();
                        mInt.notify();
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Odd() " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Odd() Ended....");
        }
    }

    class Even extends Thread {
        private final String TAG = Even.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Even() Started....");
            synchronized (mInt) {
                try {
                    while (mInt.get() < 10)
                    {
                        while (mInt.get() % 2 != 0) {
                            mInt.wait();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "Even " + mInt.get());
                        mInt.inc();
                        mInt.notify();
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Even() " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Even() Ended....");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mInt = new Value();
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mInt.set();
                Even even = new Even();
                even.start();

                Odd odd = new Odd();
                odd.start();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Value {
    private int member;

    public Value() {
        member = 0;
    }

    public int get() {
        return member;
    }

    public void inc() {
        this.member++;
    }

    public void set() {
        this.member = 0;
    }

    public void dec() {
        this.member--;
    }
}
```